# Value of type 'StorageReference' has no member 'data'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-storage

This code would have worked a few months ago, I have checked some other code on GitHub and verified that this code would have worked in the past but I am having trouble finding a solution. I've looked for a solution using Firebase [Migration Support](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/naming-migration-guide), but I've had no luck. Thank you in advance!

```
    func configCell(searchDetail: Search) {

    self.searchDetail = searchDetail

    nameLbl.text = searchDetail.username

    let ref = Storage.storage().reference(forURL: searchDetail.userImg)

    //Error Below, highlighting 'ref.data' Error: Value of type 'StorageReference' has no member 'data'. 

    ref.data(withMaxSize: 1000000, completion: { (data, error) in

        if error != nil {

            print(" we couldnt upload the img")

        } else {

            if let imgData = data {

                if let img = UIImage(data: imgData) {

                    self.userImage.image = img
                }
            }
        }

    })
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the migration guide that you have added, you need to now use new `getData(maxSize:completion:)` instead of `data(withMaxSize:completion:)`. So make it like this.

```
ref.getData(maxSize: 1000000, completion: { (data, error) in

    if error != nil {

        print(" we couldnt upload the img")

    } else {

        if let imgData = data,let img = UIImage(data: imgData) {
            self.userImage.image = img
        }
    }

})
```

Comment: Oh my goodness, thank you so much. Sorry for not catching that.

Comment: @AladdinAl-Khatib Welcome mate :)

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/naming-migration-guide